# How to set button to column number 2 in datagridview (windows form application)

Tags: c#, winforms

[Datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlwmG.png)

```
adp = new MySqlDataAdapter("select PatientID,PatientName,PatientIdentityCard from patient where PatientName like '%" + this.searchbar.Text + "%' ", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            searchgrid.DataSource = dt;
            DataGridViewButtonColumn btn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            searchgrid.Columns.Add(btn);
            btn.HeaderText = "Consultation Registration";
            btn.Text = "Add";
            btn.Name = "btn";
            btn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            consultationlistgrid.Columns.Add("Numbering", "No.");
```

while search button is clicked, query will load the data into data grid,
the button is hard code add into the datagridview.

any one can provide me the source code to reallocate the button position?

Comment: first of all provide us more info - how your grid is created, give some code samples of your tryings etc.

Comment: You obviously have some code to do something close to what you want.  Please share it so we can see what you did wrong and help you.  Please read [ask] and visit the [help] to learn how the site works

Comment: @MaciejS. i just updated the code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this code sample:

```
btn.DisplayIndex = 1;
```

Value of 1 will put your column to second position in gridview. You can use other value than 1 ofcourse.

You can find more info about DisplayIndex property here: [DisplayIndex Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex?view=netframework-4.7.2)

If my answer is correct, please mark it as answer.